# No routes matching in rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

When i submit the below new.html.erb it goes to `http://localhost:3000/user/new_user_by_admin` and it shows error : No route matches "/user/new_user_by_admin" with {:method=>:post}. I want this page to be submitted to `http://localhost:3000/users/new_user_by_admin`. What changes do i need?

```
<% form_for :user,:url => url_for { :controller => :user ,:action => :new_user_by_admin, :method => :post }  do |f| %>
    <p><%= f.label :login %><br/>
            <%= f.text_field :login %></p>

            <p><%= f.label :name %><b`enter code here`r/>
            <%= f.text_field :name %></p>

            <p><%= f.label :email %><br/>
            <%= f.text_field :email %></p>

            <p><%= f.label :password %><br/>
            <%= f.password_field :password %></p>

            <p><%= f.label :password_confirmation, 'Confirm Password' %><br/>
            <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></p>
            <p><%= submit_tag 'Sign up' %></p>
        <% end %>
```

code for user controller is:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
def new_user_by_admin
      @user=User.new(params[:user])
      @user.save
      redirect_to("/users/")
  end
end
```

code for routes.rb is:

```
ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|
  map.home '' , :controller => 'users', :action => 'index'
  map.logout '/logout', :controller => 'sessions', :action => 'destroy'
  map.login '/login', :controller => 'sessions', :action => 'new'
  map.register '/register', :controller => 'users', :action => 'create'
  map.signup '/signup', :controller => 'users', :action => 'new'
  map.adduser '/new_user_by_admin', :controller => 'users', :action => 'new_user_by_admin', :method => :post

  map.resources :users
  map.resource :session
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
end
```

Help!!

Comment: please check with rake:routes

Answer (score 0):

your matching is wrong. It should be:

when you do:

```
map.adduser '/new_user_by_admin', :controller => 'users', :action => 'new_user_by_admin', :method => :post
```

you are matching the action to url localhost:3000/new_user_by_admin instead of the one you actually want. Try the one below:

```
map.adduser '/users/new_user_by_admin', :controller => 'users', :action => 'new_user_by_admin', :method => :post
```

will match your controller action to localhost:3000/users/new_user_by_admin

Comment: map.new_user_by_admin '/new_user_by_admin', :controller => 'users', :action => 'new_user_by_admin'

Answer (score 0):

```
map.new_user_by_admin '/new_user_by_admin', :controller => 'users', :action => 'new_user_by_admin'
```

This changes i have done for the solution of above problem in routes.rb file